# Meteor. Cannot find module 'request'

Tags: meteor

When I try to give new commands I get errors.

```
[root@localhost ~]# meteor

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (module.js:370:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/deploy.js:9:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the node_modules are missing or the NODE_PATH is set incorrectly.

Try re-installing or debugging this, or try to create a dev_bundle instead from a git clone if the normal approach doesn't work for you...